# os.mkdir(os.path.join($folder1,$folder2)) adding "\" before $folder2 when running with shell wrapper

Tags: python, operating-system, strip

I wrote a shell/SGE wrapper for a python script for image analysis research. The first step in my python script is to make folders to copy the output of my python script `SC_qc.py` for each subject (as seen below):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor
This is a temporary script file.
"""

import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nibabel as nib
import sys
import os


# Get subject IDs and put them in list
txtfile = sys.argv[1]
subjects = [ s.strip() for s in open(txtfile, 'r').readlines() ]

comp_space = "\\\\share\\org\\comp_space\\doej\\SC_QC\\"
sc_space = "\\\\share\\org\\projects\\autism\\Protocols\\StructuralConnectivity\\"

for folder in subjects:
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(comp_space,folder))
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
```

The problem is, there seems to be a "/" added before the subject ID which is stored as `folder` from the `subjects` variable (obtained by the loop/iteration over the text file of subject ids `subjects`).

```
Executing on: 2118ffn001
Executing in: /share/org/projects/autism/
Executing at: Tue Jun 27 16:46:04 EDT 2023
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/comp_space/doej/SC_qc.py", line 25, in <module>
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(comp_space,folder))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\share\\org\\comp_space\\doej\\SC_QC\\/subject_01'
```

The folder `\\\\\share\\org\\comp_space\\doej\\SC_QC\\` itself exists, and I did attempt to use `dos2unix` to no avail (got the same error).

Is there any chance I should use `sed` to remove a hidden character from my text file, and what could be that hidden character? Or is there something wrong with how I am reading `subjects` as a variable in
`subjects = [ s.strip() for s in open(txtfile, 'r').readlines() ]`? My `txtfile` variable is just all my subject IDs listed one per line in a text file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this means that `folder` is `"/subject_01"`. You could look through txtfile to see. That leaves the question how messed up this file could be and whether its contents should be fixed or an error raised for the bad stuff.

Comment: @tdelaney If `comp_space` really ends with ```\\``` and `folder` is just `subject_01`, the result will be `...\\/subject_01`. I would expect `comp_space` to only have _one_ trailing backslash by looking at the code though.

Answer (score 1):

[`Pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is your friend for simplifying things.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nibabel as nib
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# Get subject IDs and put them in list
txtfile = sys.argv[1]
# It's much safer to use `with` when opening files.
with open(txtfile, 'r') as f:
    subjects = f.read().splitlines()

# Assuming you're using windows, these should turn out as expected. I tested them with `PureWindowsPath`
comp_space = Path("\\\\share\\org\\comp_space\\doej\\SC_QC\\")
sc_space = Path("\\\\share\\org\\projects\\autism\\Protocols\\StructuralConnectivity\\")

for folder in subjects:
    # Make the directory and all necessary parent directories, (parents=True) 
    # If it already exists, don't raise an error. (exists_ok=True)
    comp_space.joinpath(folder).mkdir(parents=True, exists_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of paths with backslashes

```
\\\\share\\org\\comp_space\\doej\\SC_QC\\
```

use regular `/`s - and don't have the trailing directory separator there. That trailing `\\` is probably messing up the path building for `os.path.join`. Instead, make it:

```
//share/org/comp_space/doej/SC_QC
```

This line in the output makes me wonder if the `share` is really a Windows share:

```
Executing in: /share/org/projects/autism/
```

If it's not, but instead a mounted (NFS or similar) filesystem, remove one `/` from the beginning of the path, which would make it

```
/share/org/comp_space/doej/SC_QC
```

However, another output mentions

```
/share/comp_space/doej/
```

which means that `/org` should be removed, making it

```
/share/comp_space/doej/SC_QC
```

Comment: Share _is_ a network share. The double backslashes at the front tell us that. If OP changes to forward slashes, "/subject_01" is now an absolute path and won't be rooted in \\\\share\\org\\comp_space\\doej\\SC_QC any more.

Comment: @tdelaney `File "/share/comp_space/doej/SC_qc.py"` looks like a non-share path. Nowhere but in OPs own code are there double backslashes

Comment: You told OP to make it `//share/org/comp_space/doej/SC_QC`, which is a network share. The problem is that if you then use an absolute path `/source_01`, the join will move it to the root of the share `//share/org/source_01`.

Comment: @tdelaney You are assuming that `folder` starts with a `/`. I wouldn't assume that. I assume that the `subjects` that it reads from `txtfile` does _not_ have `/` first.

Comment: Its not an assumption. The error says the path is `'\\\\share\\org\\comp_space\\doej\\SC_QC\\/subject_01'` and the only way you can get there is if `folder` is `"/subject_01"`. I asked OP to verify in the source text, but haven't heard anything back.

Comment: @tdelaney No, that's not the only way. `comp_space = "SC_QC\\\\"` `folder = "subject_01"` `p = os.path.join(comp_space,folder)` makes `p` into `SC_QC\\/subject_01` - at least on linux where I think this is executed.

Comment: I'd follow the answer recommending `Pathlib`, with the exception that every instance of `"\\"` should be replaced by the `Path` `/` operator, which will insert the correct separator for the current OS. There are also methods for handling root and drive strings as well.

Comment: @JohnBayko That's probably wise. At least if portability with Windows is needed. Good thing Windows accepts `/` as a directory separator too so even when using hardcoded paths with `/`, it'll likely succeed. UNC shares may be the exception. Haven't looked into that.

Comment: `Pathlib` correctly converts ``\\`` to `/` under the hood in windows, so it shouldn't matter either way~

Comment: @BeRT2me It seems like a bit of overkill to use `PathLib` for converting hardcoded paths inside the script though. Simply use forward slashes and no trailing directory separators.

Comment: One method requires that OP knows what they're doing and understands the difference between forward, backward, and trailing slashes. Which, although it may be a good thing to know - they simply may not need/care to know. So you're right... but we're catering to someone using `Spyder`... `Pathlib` also gives access to its slightly smarter `joinpath` and `mkdir` methods - which also reduce mistakes and limit the need for manual error handling.